# how do I get a snap of a directshw stream

Tags: c#, .net, directshow

I am using the directshow.net to capture video from the camera. The video is visible on a form. Can someone tell me how I can take a snap of it as an .NEt Image object. I need to take snaps of it intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a sample application that shows you how to do this with DirectShow.net.  When you download the SDK, look for the DxSnap demo.  This shows how to take a screenshot of a webcam's video stream.  You can modify it to fit your scenario but this should be all you need.

Even on this site, however, Microsoft recommends that you use WIA (Windows Image Acquisition) to accomplish this instead.  Just in case you have the option and haven't come across this before, here is a tutorial on how to get started:

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Look-at-me-Windows-Image-Acquisition